# Getting width and height of a Shape object in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, geometry, 2d

I have a method that takes any subclass of `Shape` (that can be `Circle`, `Rectangle`, `Polygon`, `Line`, etc...) and returns a `Shape` object.

```
public Shape returnShapeObject() {
   return circle1;
}
```

The problem is that once I get the shape object representation of my circle, it no longer has a `.getRadius()` method. It doesn't have `.getWidth()` or `.getHeight()` either.

How can I get the radius/width/height of a Shape object in 2d JavaFX then?

Comment: `Shape` is an `abstract` class, it doesn't have the functions defined in the extended classes like `Circle` etc. In case you want to use a specific method you need to cast the `shape` object e.g. for `Circle` you can use `((Circle) shape).getRadius();` and accordingly for other subclasses of `Shape`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can utilize the method `Node#getLayoutBounds()` as:

```
List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
shapes.add(new Circle(30));
shapes.add(new Rectangle(200, 200));
shapes.add(new Text("some arbitrary long text for testing"));
for (Shape shape : shapes) {
    System.out.println("bounds = " + shape.getLayoutBounds());
    System.out.println("width  = " + shape.getLayoutBounds().getWidth());
    System.out.println("height = " + shape.getLayoutBounds().getHeight());
}
```

Be cautioned to read the javadoc of that method carefully.

If you want a concrete shape's methods and properties then you should to do down casting as @AKS mentioned in his comment.